# How to get meta value based on latest post id with group by term name

Tags: meta-query, post-meta

my query is

```
SELECT terms.name as artist_name,
wposts.ID,wpostmeta1.meta_value as image 
FROM wp_posts wposts 

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpostmeta1 ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta1.post_id and wpostmeta1.meta_key = 'fb_thumb' 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms terms ON (terms.term_id = term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' 
AND term_taxonomy.parent = 1160 
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
group by terms.name limit 1;
```

i need to get meta value based on latest post,i was got same terms.name multiple time so i have used group by terms.name but i have problem with meta_value,i am getting first post id meta value instead of latest post id meta value

my attempt was but no luck

```
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wposts1 ON wposts.ID < wposts1.ID
```

problem is

**how to retrive the last record in each group with wordpress custom query**

please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) i have same probelm with wordpress custom query but i dont know how to use this solution with wordpress custom query

Comment: The title os your question is `How to get meta value` and the description says `i need to get terms.name`. Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/202819/edit) and try to explain again what you are trying to do and where do you have problems?

Comment: @cybmeta i have updated my question